# Getting RPi-Cam-Web-Interface running

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, raspbian, motion

I followed the tutorial on [this](http://elinux.org/RPi-Cam-Web-Interface) site, to get my RaspberryPi NoIR-Cam running. After starting it i am retrieving the following error:

```
mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
sh: 1: /var/www/html/macros/error_hard.sh: Permission denied
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)
```

This looks like a permission thing, but I executed

```
chmod u+x *.sh
```

just like they mentioned in the tutorial. Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Explanation: It is a permission problem, the RPi interface is trying to use the pi camera at the same time as something else, and that something else has root privileges.

I have used this interface before to stream PiCamera data into a webserver, and use three.js to render it and make it vr compatible. This RPi web interface is pretty frustrating for me. But, I have had that problem before. First, check your camera connection to the pi. To do this type `raspistill -t 0` into the terminal. If it brings up a preview window, that is not the problem, if it doesn't bring up a preview window, fiddle with the connection and try again. Next, if that doesn't work, run `./RPi_Cam_Web_Interface_Installer.sh`. This should bring up a crude GUI. Use your arrow keys to select number 4, or start camera. Once it starts, it should say 'started' next to it. You may get an error message at the bottom saying `mmal: mmal_component_create_core: could not create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1)
sh: 1: /var/www/html/macros/error_hard.sh: Permission denied
mmal: mmal_vc_component_create: failed to create component 'vc.ril.camera' (1:ENOMEM)`   (or the same error you got). To fix this, close the terminal, open up a new one, and `cd RPi_Web_Interface` and then run again `./RPi_Web_Interface_Installer.sh` select configure, enable autostart and camera. Then reboot. When the pi boots up, immediately open a terminal `cd RPi_Web_Interface` and `./RPi_Web_Interface_Installer.sh` and check if the camera is started (you will know because the green started message will be next to the start option). If it isn't started, start it. IF you get the same error messages, I don't know what to tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Had this exact error so:
ran sudo raspi-config and re-enabled the camera -problem went away